Snapcraft ruby plugin
Looks like there is no ruby plugin for core22, and local plugins are no longer supported. Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to snap a ruby application?

If a particular this does not work, please let us know https://snapcraft.io/docs/ruby-applications

The instructions on this page result in:
"RuntimeError: ERROR: base 'core18' was last supported on Snapcraft 7 available on the '7.x' channel."
I'm trying to update to core22/core24.
